# Get duplicated record's row values as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have so messed up database records that I am trying to correct. I am having trouble coming up with the query.

Basically, this is how my data looks:

```
   ---------------
   | Id | Value  |
   ---------------
   | 1  | John   |
   | 2  | John   |
   | 3  | Nick   |
   | 4  | Nick   |
   | 5  | Tom    |
   | 7  | Tom    |
   ---------------
```

I need the output to be

```
-------------------------------
   | Value |   Id1 |   Id2 |
   -------------------------------
   | John  |   1   |   2   |
   | Nick  |   3   |   4   |
   | Tom   |   5   |   7   |
   -------------------------------
```

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at two values, it could be as simple as

```
Select value
      ,id1 = min(ID)
      ,id2 = max(ID)
 From  YourTable
 Group By value
```

> **EDIT - If more than two observations**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID
              ,Value
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by value order by id)
         From  YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(ID) for RN in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) pvt
```